# How do I check if a certain application is running by its file name?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

How do I check if a **certain application** is running by its file name? Or if that's not possible, then by its command line? I know "pkill" has the option "-f" but I don't need to kill it, just check.

Update:

I want to get the status of a **certain** application(s) only in bash, preferable if I don't need to filter the output to lookup up the status of the app I want to check the status of.

If that matters, it's a python or ruby script, I need to check the status for them both.

Comment: Depends. Is that a GUI app ? or console ?

Comment: @Serg, console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since you've asked how to check if a process is running or not when you know its name , then it's a simple `pgrep` operation. Alternatively, one could use `ps` and specify `state` options for formating

```
$ ps --no-headers -C firefox -o args,state                     
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox    R
```

State code is on the right. From `man ps` you can know their meaning:

```
       D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
       R    running or runnable (on run queue)
       S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
       T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is
            being traced
       W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
       X    dead (should never be seen)
       Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by
            its parent
```

**Original**

Most of the time console apps run with their own name. If it's a script, with a `!#` line on the top, it will run with an interpreter specified with that line, for instance a bash script:

```
$ ps -ef | grep batmon
root      2108     1  0 22:22 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/xieerqi/bin/batmon.sh
```

However there are scripts that server as *wrapper* for other applications.For instance `gnome-terminal` is actually a script which calls `gnome-terminal.real`

What you always put an app into background , which will tell you a pid of that process

```
$ bin/batmon.sh &                                              
[1] 3224
```

You then can use `kill PID` (for example here `kill 3224`) to close app directly, or use `ps` to find its name:

```
$ ps --no-headers -p 3224 -o %a                                
/bin/bash bin/batmon.sh
```

In general, `pkill` can search for the names given without `-f` , which stands for full name. You could also search using `pgrep appNamePartial`

Comment: ты что-то намудрил. нужно просто проверить запущен ли питон скрипт по имени его файла. все. как?

Comment: Я в самом начале так и написал - скрипт будет запущен той программой для которой он написан - тут нет ничего сложного.

Comment: обновил мой вопрос.

Comment: @Mr.Mister Gentlemen, please could we enjoy the discussion?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Definitely !  Basically , OP needs to know status of a file , whether its running or not. The original question was worded poorly . . . .So basically a `pgrep` or actually `ps` with status option

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Note that the advantage of `pgrep` or `pgrep -f` is that it filters itself out of the search. (like `ps -ef | grep <scriptname> | grep -v grep`)

Comment: @JAcobVlijm nice to know. Never noticed this behavior

Answer (score 3):

If you want to live track the processes you can have the famous command:

```
top
```

but you want it by filename so you will need to add a parameter as:

```
top -c
```

Comment: Yup, that's good too. In general  any app that can monitor processes or search for process names can be used. `top`, `htop`, `ps` , `pgrep` - doesn't matter, it's all applicable